# Java - how do I take date as input and be able to add/subtract its days/months/years

Tags: java, date, intellij-idea

I'm currently using this code and I don't know if there is a way to add or subtract the date that I input with `Scanner(System.in)`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Date: ");
String date = scanner.next();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date2=null;
try {
    date2 = dateFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Never use the legacy classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use only *java.time* classes.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

To add and subtract, call the `plus…` and `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate later = ld.plusDays( 3 ) ;
LocalDate earlier = ld.minusYears( 7 ) ;
```

Comment: Should I still use the scanner class to get input

Comment: @brae Yes, the part of the code reading user input is unchanged from the question. Only the code in the answer assumes that the variable holding the string read from the scanner is named `input` rather than `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Date to LocalDate. Its has plus methods, like plusYears(),plusMonths(),plusDays().

```
    // Date -> LocalDate
    private static LocalDate of(Date date) {
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        return instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }
 
    // LocalDate -> Date
    private static Date of(LocalDate localDate) {
        Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        return Date.from(instant);
    }
```

Comment: Your conversions are correct, but the OP is better helped by not using the `Date` class at all and hence not needing the conversions.